# DRF Serializer field's queryset not updating

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a Django models:

```
class Author(Model):
  name = CharField(max_length=256)

class Library(Model):
  address = CharField(max_length=256)
  books = ManyToManyField(Book)

class Book(Model):
  name = CharField(max_length=256)
  created_by = ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

I want Author to create new Libraries with Books by sending array with IDs, but limit book choices to only the ones created by author making request. I want this serializer to reject all books if author is not given. I have a serializer:

```
class LibrarySerializer(ModelSerializer):
  books = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Book.objects.none())
  
  class Meta:
    model = Library
    fields = ("books", "address")

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.author = kwargs.pop("author", None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.author:
      self.fields["books"].queryset = Book.objects.filter(created_by=self.author)
```

Now I run:

```
author = Author(name="John")
author.save()
book = Book(created_by=author, name="book_one")
book.save()

serializer = LibrarySerializer(data={"books": [book.id], "address": "address_one"}, author=author)
```

But when I validate the serializer by calling `serializer.is_valid()` there is an errors saying that given book does not exist. Do you know why it is rejected or how can I investigate that?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change serializer's field into:

```
books = ListField(child=PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Book.objects.none()))
```

and in constructor:

```
self.fields["books"].child.queryset = Book.objects.filter(created_by=self.author)
```

Comment: Likely you don't have to change the `books = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Book.objects.none())`, `.child` will be sufficient, since `many=True` will wrap it in a `ListField`.